# I want to fit an image with a heading

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

```
<style>

.dazzlebox{
background-image: url("img/g954.png"); 
width:30%;
margin-top:-220px;
margin-left:650px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

I want the view just like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Pm5.png)

```
.dazzlebox h1{
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:70px;
}


</style>

<div class="dazzlebox" >        
          <h1>WHY YOU SHOULD GET A DAZZLE  <span class="duzzale-box" style="font-family:Coneria Script Demo" >Box</span> </h1>

                             <img src="./img/g1158.png" style="width:20px; padding-left:170px; display:inline-block;">
```

I want to fit the "heart" image just with the word Box. When ever I give the padding or margin it moves with the heading.

```
                 </div>
```

[image: The display I want]

Comment: You want to add it under the word "Box"?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML too? And also please explain what do you mean by "heart." Maybe a preferred screenshot from your favorite image editor might help

Comment: Generally large fixed-unit margins and paddings are a bad idea (they won't work responsively). You'll be much better off making use of something like `float: right`, or `position: absolute` in conjunction with `right: 0`.

Comment: yes I want the image in the same line just with the word "Box" .

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? The link you've provided is broken

View in fullpage:

```css
#main_container {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/1200px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-family: Coneria Script Demo;
}

h1,
span {
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 83%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_container">
  <h1>WHY YOU SHOULD GET A DAZZLE</h1>
  <div id="container"><span>BOX</span></div>
</div>
```